# Create a Live ISO from a directory

Tags: linux, bootable

Heyo, I've been working on a small distro of mine, and have stitched together a system. Now, I'd like to be able to use this to create a live install ISO. I've looked into ways, but what I found was a tool that you can install via apt. (I couldn't even use that because I'm on Portage). Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: For clarification, I'm looking for a USB which someone can plug into their computer, boot to it, and run my install script. It would be nice if it was live, as well.

Comment: Maybe look at https://www.linux-live.org/ ?

Comment: An ISO is fixed, so future changes would not be incorporated. Better to have good backup procedures and know how to restore from backup. That then works for both the case where hard drive fails & you have to reinstall or just want another install with same configuration & settings. All your user settings are in /home. You data is in /home or other data partition(s) you may have created. You can export list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall them. If you have installed server type apps, then you have to also back up those from / (root) folders. System settings changes are in /etc.

Comment: @icarus I have seen that - but can I make an ISO from my directory?

Comment: @oldfred This distro is completely from scratch, I'd have to backup everything, including the binary built system applications and kernel... I'm looking for a live USB!

Comment: Do you want a `live` device or a `live install` device? Does it need to work for anything other than your current hardware configuration? What exactly are you trying to do? Are you looking to create a USB/CD/DVD that you can use to recreate your hard disk if it fails, or do you want something you can give to a friend and say "check out my distro"? This seems to be an https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378

Comment: @icarus Hrm, you seem to be correct - I will update my question. I want a live install device, where they can run one install script that will build the distro. It would be nice if it was a live device, so they could boot into the distro and "play around with it" as they say. Thanks, and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Get application like [Brasero](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Brasero). Select your files and have it build the iso for you.
On Windows you can use Rufus or ImgBurn software that are solid.

Solution 2:
It looks like you are looking for the [genisoimage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/genisoimage) command or the [dd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) command.

With genisoimage, you can use the following command line to get a Live ISO:

```
sudo genisoimage -o "<ISO_NAME.iso>" -r -V "<IMAGE_NAME>" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table </PATH/TO/YOUR/DIRECTORY>
```

NOTE: To create a live/bootable ISO image, you probably want to follow your desired distribution's instructions [like here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch#Create_ISO_Image_for_a_LiveCD) or [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example start to finish . >>
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and the OP will need to type-copy command examples when trying to apply your solution. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.